# All Mac OS X apps crash as opened

Tags: macos, mac, crash, osx-mountain-lion

After I've reinstalled Mac OS X 10.8 and transfered my back-up folders to my MacBook Pro (late 2011), all Mac OS apps started to crash as I open them. I'm talking about apps like Mail, Safari, Keychain Access, System Preferences, but also some other apps like Xcode or Skype. I've tried to format the whole HDD and re-intall the OS and retransfer my back-up files, nothing changed. I also can't access some sites like gmail.com or do some googling directly from the navigation bar of Google Chrome - it says that the webpage is not available (not sure if the issues are related but started at the same time).

What should I do to use the computer correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there is some error in config files in your backup that is causing the crashes. Reinstall 10.8, but ***don't*** restore your backups yet, just keep them in an accessible place. Reboot and verify that things work properly. Then, start transferring your backups over a little bit at a time and see where the problem is. This is just a guess, but since most personal configurations are stored in the `Library` folder in your home directory (`/Users/YourLoginName/Library`) I would hold off on that folder until the very end. Unfortunately, it can become a very large folder, so you'll have to transfer subdirectories of `~/Library` one at a time, and especially the subdirectories of `~/Library/Application Support`, as this is the most likely place where the error is.

If you run into problems along the way, post at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com), a sister site to this one (your login should transfer over) that is specifically about Apple software and hardware.

Good luck!

Comment: How do I transfer backups _over a little bit at a time_? I'm just using restore from Time Machine Back-up...

Comment: what exactly are you restoring from Time Machine? If you've backed up your entire system, and are then replacing it after reinstalling, you haven't really done anything. Does your computer work if you reinstall, but don't restore anything yet?

Comment: After re-installing the OS, I'm chosing restore files from time machine back-up while setting up the system. When I don't restore anything, all works fine.

Comment: well, Time Machine is acting up on my computer at the moment, so I can't walk you through it, unfortunately. So, don't choose to restore files when setting up the system, because you aren't given the option of choosing which to restore, right? Then, after you reboot into your clean install, you *should* be able to open Time Machine and choose what to restore, hopefully on a directory by directory basis. Try restoring everything except `/Users/UserName/Library/Application Support` and see if that has any effect. If that works OK, try restoring directories inside the (continued)...

Comment: `/Users/UserName/Library/Application Support` hierarchy, **except** the `Apple` directory. Maybe start with one or two innocuous applications at first, and verify that they work, then restore some more.

Comment: Instead of doing all this thing will it have some effects if erease the Application Support directory (backing it up to somewhere else) and copying from the back-up?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9050/discussion-between-mattdmo-and-moray95)

Answer (score 1):

I'd also try to [do an upgrade install of OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10763?viewlocale=en_US) from the recovery partition. It should replace system files with the initial versions but keep most user files and setting in place. It fixed an issue I had where [different processes crashed on launch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83282/systemuiserver-and-other-processes-crash-repeatedly-on-login).

If that doesn't work, do a clean reinstall again, but restore only a part of the files. You can use [Migration Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10763?viewlocale=en_US) to transfer only users or settings, but I have always just copied files manually from Finder.

I don't think it's likely that the issues are caused by files in the Application Support directory though.

Comment: What's an upgrade install? If you talking about re-installing the OS, I've done it many times.

Comment: I meant choosing Reinstall OS X from the recovery partition without erasing the OS X volume first. "Reinstalling OS X" is ambiguous because it can mean a clean reinstall (like you did earlier) or an upgrade install (patching the current installation).

Comment: I've also reinstalled the OS from recovery partition without formatting, nothing changes